# How did the door open just by playing the recorded code?

Tags: wargames-1983

In the 1983 science fiction film *Wargames*, David was locked in the facility's infirmary room. He searched the drawers and found some scissors and a mini-tape recorder. He tricked the guard into opening the door and made a recording of the code. He then played the recording near the door and it opened.

[image]

**How did the door open just by playing the recorded code?**

Comment: Maybe the writers couldn't think of a more plausible way to get out?

Comment: I just assumed the door lock, for whatever reason, was dial-tone based.

Comment: To close voters: "questions seeking scientific solutions or explanations are off-topic ***unless related directly to a cited work of fiction.*** [...]" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He recorded the electronic code-sequence onto the magnetic tape, then played the tape back to replay the code-sequence into the locking mechanism. The fact that we can hear audible tones seems to be largely incidental.

> Cautiously he placed the panel on the floor, then rose up and peered into the control wiring and retrieved the cassette recorder, wired into the mechanism with the earphone cord.
>   He rewound the tape and moved the jack from “input” to “output.” This was it!
>   His forefinger hit the “play” button.
>   **Faint tones sounded—an exact repetition of the unlocking sequence. The door lock hummed quietly and clicked.** Then, with malicious glee in his eye, he pulled a very important wire.
>
> <sub><sup>[War Games: Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/74328.War_Games)</sup></sub>

And yes, I'm aware that this is dumb, but that's Hollywood for you.

Comment: It's only dumb because you don't understand it

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Touché, sir.

Comment: It's not dumb at all. My dad's first desktop PC used cassette tapes instead of floppy disks or a hard drive. You put the tape into the cassette player (which was just a plain cassette player that you could use to play music on), and played the tape. It's basically the same technology as a floppy disk anyway - magnetic storage media. Only instead of storing it on a flat disk, you're storing it on a strip of tape.

Comment: @Jonathan - This assumes that the lock outputs the keystrokes in the same frequency range as the tape is designed to record. It's theoretically possible, but in reality dumb because they don't do that.

Comment: That's not how it worked. It isn't recording audio, it's recording electrical inputs. Hard disks, floppy disks, cassette tapes - it's all the same technology. Mainframes have been using reel to reel tape backups for decades, which are just oversize cassette tapes.

Comment: @Jonathan - Magnetic tape is only capable of recording in input in [certain frequencies](http://www.open.edu/openlearn/science-maths-technology/engineering-and-technology/technology/revolutions-sound-recording/content-section-1.3.3). Ignoring that keypads don't play tunes (because it's an obvious security fail) they certainly don't output a button-push signal at an audio frequency.

Comment: Probably inspired by [phreaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phreaking) which took advantage of the phone systems' use of pulses/tones to control routing - there's quite a few things the movie does that look cool but aren't really plausible (the gradual unlocking of the password, for example), but you can see where they might have gotten the idea from

Comment: This was apparently a DTMF driven lock - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling.

Comment: That keypad's output would still be outside the normal range of an audio-cassette *to record*.