# How does Spider-Man use a calculator to open the vault door in Spider-Man Homecoming?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

When locked in the vault, Spider-Man with the help of Karen uses his calculator to open the door, how did he do that?

Comment: We don't answer "real world science" questions, although your question definitely applies in-universe and is pretty interesting!

Comment: It was typical Hollywood computer hacking BS.

Comment: He used calculator just as an input device and tried every possible sequence with the time circuit he wanted to reset.. If I remember correctly, his trial 247 succeeded..

Comment: @Don't Panic I remember Peter said something like 'Karen now increase the voltage.'

Comment: @BernardtheBear I've edited out the "Real world science" sentence to keep it on-topic and ensure your question doesn't get wrongfully closed.

Comment: It was a modern adaptation of the [WarGames method](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/183841/20490).

Comment: I think he was just using it as a hotwired input device, like @Don'tPanic said.

Answer (score 3):

Peter Parker was either using the calculator to try and short circuit the system or calculate the options. For the short circuit aspect it would increase the voltage to override the max electricity used causing it to blow out and open the door hence why he said "up the voltage". But on the other hand he might have been using the calculator for its basic use and do math. He would have been calculating what he needs to do to open the door. Hope this helps, thanks.